# Superfluous assumption in a counterexample to Frobenius algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

In the [wikipedia entry on Frobenius algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra), there are some examples and counter-examples. In example 5, where do you need that $\operatorname{char}(k) \neq 2$ ? I think $R:= k[x,y]/ (x,y)^2$ is *never* a Frobenius algebra, in fact it is not QF because the well-defined $R$-linear map $Rx \rightarrow R$ induced by $x \mapsto y$ does not lift to the whole ring, so $R$ is not self-injective.

I see that maybe one cannot argue as in example 2 because of the usual problems with bilinear forms in characteristic 2, but anyway this would only show the failure of one sufficent criterion, and seems more confusing than enlightening. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always possible, of course, that the author was just "playing it safe", and was only familiar with the proof using their favorite definition.

I think your approach is good though: in the $R$ specified, if the map sending $x\mapsto y$ from $Rx$ to $R$ were extended to an $R$ linear map $\phi:R\to R$, then $x\phi(1)=\phi(x)=y$. But "$\phi(x)=x\phi(1)=y$" is impossible since $xR=Rx=kx$.

If you enjoy editing wikipedia, you might take a shot at improving the example :)